# Regarding fonts in various locations of book class

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, fontsize, page-numbering

I am using the book class. I am not interested in using Memoir. I need to be able to change the font and size of the word "Contents" which appears at the beginning of the ToC. I can do this now (demonstrated below). I also need to be able to change the font and size of the word "CONTENTS" which appears on the second page header of the ToC. I also need to be able to change the font and size of the page numbers throughout the document.

Any help would be great!

The below demonstrates the ability to change the table of contents font and size, but not the header for the ToC on the 2nd page of the ToC. It also does not yet address changing the font and size for the page numbers.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\begin{document}

\chapterfont{\normalsize}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The First Book of Moses, Called Genesis}
In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The title of the table of contents has the same size as the other chapter titles; the same is for the header. Can you be more specific about your needs?

Comment: On the 2nd page of a table of contents, there is the word "CONTENTS" in the header. I need to be able to modify that. I would like to change its font and its size.

Comment: Also, there are page numbers all throughout the book which I cannot modify the font or size for.

Comment: Perhaps `fancyhdr`?

Comment: I would prefer to just edit using the book class... packages like fancyhdr and memoir seem to make a lot of changes to the entire document. Thank you for the suggestion, though. What variable modifies page number font without using packages that modify the overall look of the book class?

Comment: @ TeXUser: You should take a look at the `titlesec` package and its companion `titleps`. They modify only what you tell them to modify.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this by hand then you need to redefine `\l@chapter` (the command used to print the 'contents line' for a chapter). Rather than write out the entire thing, I'd favour doing a patch. For example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\l@chapter
  {\leavevmode}
  {%
    \leavevmode
    \LARGE
  }%
  {}
  {\ERROR}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\chapterfont{\normalsize}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The First Book of Moses, Called Genesis}
In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth. 

\end{document}
```

will add `\LARGE` at the start of the font settings for the contents line. There is a `\bfseries` just after the `\leavevmode` in `\l@chapter`, so if you don't want it bold do something like

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\l@chapter
  {\bfseries}
  {%
    \LARGE
  }%
  {}
  {\ERROR}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\chapterfont{\normalsize}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The First Book of Moses, Called Genesis}
In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: The question has multiple parts, which is not a great fit for the site style. I've tried to cover what seems to be the main part.